# splitter.js with jquery 1.10 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, splitter

I'm using following libraries in my project:

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js
splitter.js (Version 1.51) downloaded from [http://www.methvin.com/splitter/splitter.js]
```

I implemented splitter to divide the screen into 2 (re-sizable) panes using `jquery-1.7.1.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js and splitter.js (version 1.51)`. It was working perfectly fine.

But now, I have updated the jquery libraries to the versions mentioned above. In these updates, `$.browser() function is removed from their code` (http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed).
But since, `splitter.js still uses $.browser()` function, I get the following error in this file:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
```

I searched on net, if there is updated version of splitter.js. I came across its `version 1.6` which I downloaded and included in my project. But, the same error is hit again; as this version also uses $.browser() function.

Could anyone tell me if there is any version of splitter.js which is **compatible with jquery-1.10.2.min.js**? Or if there is any work-around for this? Or should I try using `jQuery Migrate plugin` (Refer this [link](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)) which uses $.browser() function?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ya, you should try to use jQuery migrate...

Comment: @A. Wolff: I tried jQuery migrate with both the versions of splitter.js (i.e. 1.51 and 1.6). The error is gone but splitter movement is little jerky. Its not smooth as it was earlier.

Answer (score 0):

$.browser is removed from jquery-1-10. You should use jQuery migrate

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/